# Isometric map in an open set of Euclidean space

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, differential-geometry, euclidean-geometry, analytic-geometry

In classical geometry, it is known that isometric maps in $\mathbb{R}^3$

(i.e. a map $T:\mathbb{R}^3\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^3$ s.t. $d(Tx,Ty)=d(x,y)$ for all points $x,y$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$)

are orthogonal transformations with translations.

$T$ is continuous by Lipschitz. Is it possible that $T$ is not $C^1$?

And I wonder what will happen when restricting to a given open set $U\subset\mathbb{R}^3$. How to decide the isometry group of $U$?

A special case is the open ball. It preserves most symmetries of the entire space. But I can't see if $T(O)\ne O$ could happen.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Hint: Repeat the classical proof (for the entire $E^n$) if  you know how it works. Maybe you should start with the case $n=1$ as a warm-up.

Comment: Do you mean an isometry in the metric sense or in the sense of Riemannian geometry?

Comment: @AndreasCap: I refer $T$ as an isometry by a map satisfying $d(Tx,Ty)=d(x,y)$. What's the difference between those two senses?

Comment: @MoisheCohen: I tried to imitate the proof in $U=\mathbb{R}^3$. But it needs the fact that translations and linear transformations are permitted. However, in the case that $U$ is a given open set, those operations are not available. I feel it has more to do with the shape of $U$. Can you give some hints to fix the gap?

Comment: @gžd15 suppose you have a local isometry fixing s point and three orthogonal segments through this point. Can you show that this local isometry is the identity on a small ball about this point? If you can then you are almost done: reduce the general case to the special by composing with a rigid motion.

Comment: @MoisheCohen I can do it with $C^1$ hypothesis. But how can I get a fixed point and 3 orthogonal segments? And what if not $C^1$?

Comment: @gžd15 first show that T maps geodesics to geodesics and preserves angles. This replaces the $C^1$ assumption.

Comment: The Riemannian geometry definition would be a sufficiently differentiable map for which the derivative in each point is orthogonal with respect to the standard scalar product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a step-by-step sketch of the proof, the details you should be able to fill in:

Let $T: U\to E^3$ be an isometric map of an open connected subset of $R^3$.

1. Show that $T$ sends geodesic (straight line) segments in $U$ to geodesic segments. (Hint: define geodesic segments in terms of triangle inequalities.)
2. Show that $T$ preserves angles $\angle(ABC)$ between geodesic segments $AB, BC$ in $U$.
3. Consider three pairwise orthogonal geodesic segments $OA, OB, OC$ in $E^3$ (I will call such a triple a "base" with the center at $O$). Show that every geodesic segment $OD$ is determined by its length and the angles that it makes with the segments $OA, OB, OC$. (Hint: Use linear algebra if you have hard time proving this via elementary geometry.)
4. Assume that $T: U\to E^3$ fixes a base at $O$ in $U$ (sends $OA$ to itself, etc). Show (using 2 and 3) that $T$ restricts to the identity on a sufficiently small  open ball $B(O,r)$  centered at $O$.
5. Let ${\mathcal B}_{\delta}$ denote the set of bases in $E^3$ such that each segment in the base has length $\delta$. Show that the group of rigid motions of $E^3$ acts transitively on ${\mathcal B}_{\delta}$.
6. Use 5 to show that given any isometric map $T: U\to E^3$ and a base $b\in {\mathcal B}_\delta$ which is entirely contained in $U$, there exists a rigid motion $g$ of $E^3$ such that $T\circ g$ fixes the base $b$. (A rigid motion is a composition of reflections.) Conclude using 4 that $T\circ g$ is the identity on the ball $B_\delta(O,r)$ where $O$ is the center of the base $b$.
7. Conclude that each isometric map $T: U\to E^3$ is **locally** a rigid motion: For every $x\in U$ there exists $\delta>0$ such that $T|B(x,\delta)$ equals the restriction of a rigid motion of $E^3$.
8. Use connectivity of $U$ to conclude that $T: U\to E^3$ is the restriction of a rigid motion. Here you will use the fact that if two rigid motions agree on a nonempty open set then they are equal.

Bonus 1: Prove the same for isometric maps of domains in the Euclidean $n$-space $E^n$.

Bonus 2: Prove the same for isometric maps of domains in the rough sphere (of any dimension) and in the hyperbolic space (of any dimension).

Comment: Fascinating! I didn't realize there is a long path to approach the final. I saw this just in a textbook about classical differential geometry of curves & surfaces in $\mathbb{R}^3$. I will try to follow your steps to see whether I can show it completely.

Comment: By the way, I notice you put a condition of "connected". Is this necessary? Also I wonder if $T$ must map $U$ into $U$ itself, since I understand "isometry group" as "on the given set", i.e. the domain & range should coincide.

Comment: @gžd15 not really necessary but I run out of steam. The general case needs one more step.

Answer (score 1):

Any isometry is obviously continuous since it is Lipschitz continuous.

The group of symmetries of $U$ is clearly a subgroup of the group of all symmetries of $\mathbb{R^3}$. Usually one finds the isometry group of such $U$ by looking at $U$ really hard, then writing down what appears to be its symmetry group, then proving that the group you wrote down is correct. There is no general procedure.

Comment: I see the continuity. But why subgroup?

Comment: @gžd15 Right, in some situations it is merely a quotient group of a subgroup. Consider all isometries on $\mathbb{R}^3$, then take all those which fix $U$ (that is clearly a subgroup), then quotient out those who fix each point of $U$. That is the group of symmetries of $U$.

Comment: I know isometries on $\mathbb{R}^3$ can carry on to $U$. But there could be an isometry on $U$ which is not an isometry on $\mathbb{R}^3$. How to eliminate this possibility then?

Comment: If there are any four non-coplanar points in $U$, then their relative position and the relative position of all other points in $\mathbb{R^3}$ is completely determined by the distances to those four points. If not, then $U$ can be reduced to a subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$, in which you can use the same argument recursively.

Answer (score 0):

Euclidean space has this amazing property: an isometry defined on a subset may be extended to an isometry of the whole space.  Most metric spaces do not have this property.

Comment: It seems convenient for proof. How to show this?